# possible to automatically convert ABNF into XML?

Tags: xml, speech-recognition, bnf, ebnf

Is it possible to automatically convert ABNF into XML? In particular, I need to convert speech recognition grammars written in ABNF into XML. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you aware of http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/, which seems to represent the same speech recognition grammars in both ABNF and XML? (I'm not familiar with it, I just stumbled upon it a few minutes ago.)

Comment: Plowing through http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/, section 1.3 states that it is possible to automatically convert an ABNF Form grammar to an XML Form grammar or the reverse.

Answer (score 1):

It should be easy to do but I'm not aware about code to do that. There are ABNF parsers for example in Sphinx4 which parse ABNF according to the grammar to the tree of rules. Then you can just dump this tree in XML form.